# For VBScript, what's the advantage of a subroutine?

Tags: function, vbscript, subroutine

I may simply misunderstand the difference between the two: If the only difference between a subroutine and a function is that a function has the option of returning a value while a subroutine does not, then in what situation would you use a subroutine? Why wouldn't you always use a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Subs when I need a 'named piece of code' that does not return any information, but is called only for its side effects. I use Functions when I need a 'named piece of code' that returns some information (and (normally) does not have side  effects). I'm glad that I can state my intentions in VBScript explicitly.

**Added: Why @AutomatedChaos' proposal (comment) is misguided:**

1. You shouldn't write code before your design is settled. Either you don't need to check the result of a file delete action (then write a Sub) or you have to (then write a Function). You may later realize that you have made a mistake, but then you'll have to change more than just the npc's type.
2. Checking an action's result in a Function is a promise that your script will **always** handle a failure of the action reasonably (because each call of the Function is obliged to check the return value). To freely give the license to call such a Function as a Sub invalidates this promise.

Comment: Thanks. So as a rule, you do not write functions that have side effects?

...Ninja Edit:
Is it unacceptable or a bad strategy to always want that named piece of code to return something? For example, it would be nice if a sub that deletes a file could return a bool confirming success or not... Since a sub doesn't do that, I'd use a function. Using that line of reasoning, I'd use a function for nearly everything.

Comment: @user974552 - let's say: if I do write a function with side effects, I know that I shouldn't.

Comment: @user974552 - Wrt your addition: I wouldn't check the results of side effects (this is scripting, not lunar landing), but if you want to, then you have a third gender of npcs: Functions that do something *and* return the outcome.

Comment: You can use subs and change them to functions if you want to have them return something in the future, because you can call a function like you call a sub: without parenthesis around the parameters and without a receiving variable that gets assigned with the return value.